# Get input separated by commas + problem getting input

Tags: c, input

I'm trying to get the input of a user in the following `param1,param2,param3`
problem is that I'm not allowed to use scanf. I want to retrieve those 3 parameters into 3 different variables but:
- I don't know how to get them because they're separated by a comma
- I can't manage to use well sscanf and from what I've seen, I don't think fgets can help me.
Ex:

```
char a1, a2, a3;
printf("Enter data\n");
sscanf(input,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]", &a1, &a2, &a3);
```

I'm not asked to type the arguments that I want. Is there something I'm missing here ?

Comment: What is the param1,2,3 type? Show the reproducable code.

Comment: You say: "I'm not allowed to use scanf." Hmm... do you think you are allowed to use `sscanf` when you can't use `scanf`? I would guess that your teacher wants you to read a single char at the time and do the parsin yourself

Comment: Are you allowed to use `fscanf()` with `stdin`?

Comment: @4386427 Yes I am allowed.

Comment: You could use `fgets()` to read the user input from stdin into your input buffer, and then parse it with sscanf() (or manually using strtok())

Comment: If you are allowed to use `sscanf` than simply use it just like `scanf` (except for giving the input as a string).

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to do that, hence the question

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, your problem isn't sscanf, but rather how to get the user input into 'input', right? That's what fgets is for, it can read the user input from stdin and write it into your input variable (which you should have defined as a char array of sufficient size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fgets` and `sscanf` like:

```
char input[10];
char a1, a2, a3;

if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
{
    if (sscanf(input, "%c,%c,%c", &a1, &a2, &a3) == 3)
    {
        // ok - go on and use a1, a2, a3
    }
    else
    {
        // not good, the input doesn't match the pattern
    }
}
else
{
    // not good, didn't get any input
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are not allowed to use `scanf`, I doubt using a variation of it like `sscanf` will be allowed. It seems the point of the exercise is that you learn how to manually parse a string.

To do that, you can take several approaches. One is reading the entire line in memory and then parsing it. Another is going character by character and doing the parsing at the same time as the reading.

Whatever you do, you have to make a loop and scan for the comma `,` character (to know when to go to the next argument) and the end line `\n` one (to stop in the last one), while copying the other characters into each string.

Comment: I am allowed to use sscanf.